# Posting multidimensional array as a value in Zend_Http_Client in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, multidimensional-array

I have to post a form element `inventory` like following structure

```
[inventory] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [inventory_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

            [inventory_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Bed 90*200
                )

            [inventory_photo] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1_bed_90x200.jpg
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [inventory_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 15
                )

            [inventory_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Bed 90*200
                )

            [inventory_photo] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1_bed_90x200.jpg
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [inventory_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 15
                )

            [inventory_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Bed 90*200
                )

            [inventory_photo] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1_bed_90x200.jpg
                )

        )

)
```

When I tried to assign this array to `inventory` in `$client->setParameterPost()`, I received `POST` values like this

```
[inventory] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [inventory_id] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [inventory_name] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Bed 90*200
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [inventory_photo] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1_bed_90x200.jpg
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [inventory_id] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 15
                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [inventory_name] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Bed 90*200
                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [inventory_photo] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1_bed_90x200.jpg
                        )

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [inventory_id] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 15
                        )

                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [inventory_name] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Bed 90*200
                        )

                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [inventory_photo] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1_bed_90x200.jpg
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I have verified my array structure that is fine. I also checked in `setParameter` method in Client.php (Zend library), no issues. Just receiving this post. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The problem is with Zend_Http_Client::_flattenParametersArray(). It discards the keys of the array while flattening them. Haven't figured the solution yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend_Http_Client ignores integer keys of multi dimensional parameters. So in your case,

```
[inventory] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [inventory_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

        [inventory_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bed 90*200
        )

        [inventory_photo] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1_bed_90x200.jpg
        )

    )
```

will be translated to

```
inventory[][inventory_id][] => 1
inventory[][inventory_name][] => Bed 90*200
inventory[][inventory_photo][] => 1_bed_90x200.jpg
```

The solution to this problem is

- either to use a class extended from Zend_Http_Client and override its method `_flattenParametersArray()`.
- or convert the params arrays to strings yourself, such as:

  ```
  $client->setParameterPost('inventory[0][inventory_id][]', 1);
  $client->setParameterPost('inventory[0][inventory_name][]', 'Bed 90*200');
  $client->setParameterPost('inventory[0][inventory_photo][]', '1_bed_90x200.jpg');
  ```